# Javascript remove object keys that are not in both objects with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

So, I have this two objects:

```
const obj1 = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'Baz',
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'Baz',
    zip: 'Zip'
  },
}
```

I want to remove "zip" from obj2 since it's not in obj1. Is there a way to do this with lodash?

EDIT: If a property is an object, it will be an object in both of them. There can't be a string with the same key of an object in the other one.

The use case is, I have a translation file and after some processing, I need to remove the ones that are no longer needed. So if I delete them in the original object (i.e. obj1) they have to be removed from the other ones (in this case, obj2.

Comment: Do you just want to filter the fields to what is available in `obj1`? For example `obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2}` and `obj2 = {a: 1, c: 3}` would only remove `c`. Also, does it need to be done on each level of the object?

Comment: And if there are nested objects, how do you handle mismatching structures? Like `obj1 = { bar: "bar" }` and `obj2 = { bar: { baz: "baz"} }`. As a generic problem this ain't trivial. What's the concrete context of this question? What's your actual problem?

Comment: I just updated the question to answer your questions, sorry for the ambiguity before

Comment: The edit doesn't address the question of nested objects.

Comment: It does, you can't have a string in place of an object. If the original has a string, the obj2 either has a string or has nothing..

Comment: okay, wish I could help, but I won't know what to do if `obj1.bar.baz` and `obj2.bar.baz` are each objects with differing keys

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using additional libraries, I can recommend looking into [deep-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff):

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'Baz',
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: {
    baz: 'Baz',
    zip: 'Zip'
  },
}

DeepDiff.observableDiff(obj2, obj1, d => {
  DeepDiff.applyChange(obj2, obj1, d)
});

console.log(obj1)
console.log(obj2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/deep-diff@1/dist/deep-diff.min.js"></script>
```